# how to fix error 403 when I try to edit page in WordPress

Tags: php, wordpress

I'm using the [Classic Editor](https://wordpress.org/plugins/classic-editor/) plugin to edit my pages on Wordpress , the whenever I try to click on the update button after editing it gives me error 403 as shown in the screen shot ..how to fix this

[image]

**NOTE**

am hosting it on Namecheap's Shared hosting using Cpanel

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`HTTP Error 403` only happens in WordPress on cPanel + Litespeed for the following cases:

1. Permissions Error: Maybe there is not enough permissions to access the file. You can do the following to check if it's permission error. Run this on terminal/SSH `chmod 755 -r /USERNAME/public_html` and check afterwards if it's working. Do note that it's not recommended to keep WordPress on this. The recommended file permissions are 755 for folders and 644 for all files, so change accordingly.
2. mod_security: `mod_security` often blocks these kinds of requests if the site is hacked or some malware script is about to run. You might wanna check if WordPress Core has changed or  your Wordpress files contain some kind of malicious codes. However, `OWASP® ModSecurity CRS` ruleset is known for creating many false-positives and that's why not enabled by default on cPanel/WHM. You can check `cPanel > ModSecurity` if it's available and turn it off for your domain and if it's not there, ask your provider to turn it off for your domain which would fix the issue. Do note disabling mod_security disables Web Application Firewall and you'll have to rely on your own WordPress firewall plugins for securing your site.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like an error in the file permissions. Anyway you can see here other solutions provided by namecheap.

https://www.namecheap.com/support/knowledgebase/article.aspx/9568/2194/my-website-is-down-what-to-do/#403